# symfony2/fos-user-bundle: Login User by Entity

Tags: session, authentication, symfony-2.1, csrf, fosuserbundle

I have a user entity in a symfony2 controller and i need to log that user in.
Apparently i do not understand how the process works with the Csrf Token and loging in a user.

What do i have to do to log in the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an user object you can login/authenticate a user programmatically

```
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(),
                                       "public", $user->getRoles());

    $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

    // Trigger login event
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")
         ->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

You need to have this classes included

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
```